# Find neighbour of a neighbour

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dplyr

I have a df listing a number of areas (`df$area`) and the areas which these shares a border with (`df$next_area`).
Starting from it i want to get a similar df but with the neighbour of its neighbour.
I wrote the following, which works, but appear extremely convoluted.
Was there a better solution?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <-     data.frame(area=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D"),next_area=c("B","C","A"    ,"C","A","B","D","C") )
    df <- df %>% group_by(area) %>% 
  summarize(next_area = list(sort(unique(as.character(next_area)))))
    df$next_area_exploded <- df$next_area
    for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
      for(j in 1:length(df$next_area[[i]])){
        df$next_area_exploded[[i]][j] <-         list(df$next_area_exploded[[which(df$area==df$next_area[[i]][j])]])
  }
}
df$next_area_exploded <- lapply(df$next_area_exploded, function(x)         unique(unlist(x)))
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df$next_next_area[[i]] <- df$next_area_exploded[[i]]    [!df$next_area_exploded[[i]] %in% df$next_area[[i]]]
  df$next_next_area[[i]] <- df$next_next_area[[i]][!df$next_next_area[[i]]     %in% df$area[[i]]]
  }
df <- df %>% unnest(next_next_area) %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  mutate(col=paste0(seq_along(area),".add")) %>%
  spread(key=col, value=next_next_area)
df$next_area<-NULL; df$next_area_exploded<-NULL 
df_final <- df %>% gather(a,next_next,c(names(df)    [grepl(".add",names(df))])) %>% select(-a) %>% filter(!is.na(next_next))
```

Comment: What is your expected output for given `df` ?

Comment: The code works, so it's `df_final`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could think about this as a graph, and for each node find all the other nodes that are at a distance of 2:

```
library(igraph)

df <-  data.frame(area=c("A","A","B","B","C","C","C","D"),
                  next_area=c("B","C","A","C","A","B","D","C") )

g = graph_from_data_frame(df)

distances(g) %>%
    as_tibble(rownames = 'area') %>%
    gather(-area, key = 'next_next_area', value = 'distance') %>%
    filter(distance == 2)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  area  next_next_area distance
  <chr> <chr>             <dbl>
1 D     A                     2
2 D     B                     2
3 A     D                     2
4 B     D                     2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. I got all area of potential the neighbour of its neighbour and choice the area, not start and neighbour.

```
df %>% 
  inner_join(df %>% 
               rename(next_area = area, 
                      next_next_area = next_area),
             by = "next_area") %>% 
  filter(area != next_next_area) %>% 
  group_by(area) %>% 
  filter(! next_next_area %in% next_area) %>% 
  ungroup()
```